# C++ Linked List Pointer to struct inside pointer to another struct

Tags: c++

How can I initialize the object `person` with the string read from `std::cin`?

The class `ListElement` represents a linked list.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Stuff {
      char* name;
      char* surname;
      Date birthday; // Also a struct Date
};

struct ListElement {
      struct Stuff* person;          // Pointer to struct Stuff 
      struct ListElement* next;      // Pointer to the next Element
};

int main() {
      char input_name[50];
      cin >> input_name >> endl;

      ListElement* const start = new ListElement();
      ListElement* actual = start;

      start->next = NULL;
      *actual->person->name = input_name;  // not working :(
}
```

Comment: Uh oh, your code is leaking. C++ is not Java.

Comment: Think twice what `*actual` would do with `actual`. It dereferences the pointer and hence `*actual->person` is syntactically wrong. Though as others mentioned, even if you get your program compiled, there are many errors and flaws.

Answer (score 0):

For these structure definitions main should look the following way

```
#include <cstring>

//...

int main() {
      char input_name[50];
      cin >> input_name >> endl;

      ListElement* const start = new ListElement();
      ListElement* actual = start;

      actual->person = new Stuff();
      actual->person->name = new char[std::strlen( input_name ) + 1];
      std::strcpy( actual->person->name, input_name );
      // other code including deleting of all allocated memory
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Stuff
{
    string name;
};

int main() {
    list<Stuff> res;

    string in;
    cin>>in;

    res.push_back(Stuff{.name=in});

    for(Stuff& p : res)
        cout<<p.name<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
g++ test.cpp -std=c++0 -o test
```

---

with no c++ containeurs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>


using namespace std;

struct Stuff {
    char* name;
    char* surname;
    Date birthday; // Also a struct Date
};

struct ListElement {
    struct Stuff* person;          // Pointer to struct Stuff 
    struct ListElement* next;      // Pointer to the next Element
};

int main() {

    ListElement l;

    string in;
    cin>>in;

    char* name = new char[in.size()+1];//+1 for \0
    ::strcpy(name,in.c_str());

    Stuff* tmp = new Stuff{
        .name=name,
        .surname = nullptr,
        //.birthday = date
        };

    l.person = tmp;
    l.next = nullptr;

    //do not forget to free Stuff.name
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate in which way this code relates to the question?

Comment: It's the same, but with c++ containers.

Comment: Nonsense, it's not _'the same with containers'_. At least you missed the `Stuff` struct then.

Comment: Ok, now, it' the same, but with not complet Stuff struct. Just the minimal.

Comment: im not allowed to change the structures... they are predefined

Comment: I added a version without changing any of your struct.

Comment: What, if any, is the formal name for the initialisation syntax being used `new Stuff {.name ... `; the `.name` part?

Comment: It's called initializer value, it's not a hack,but it woks just with struct.

Comment: Thanks, just genuinely didn't know what it was called.